ASP.NET Core 8 MVC : controller send wrong form
I'm writing an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC web app. I have two controllers of the same name in different folders, one inherits from ControllerBase and the other one inherits from Controller.
The Controller implementation has two functions called Delete:
// GET: ProjectsController/Delete/5
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpRequest request = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.Request;

        Uri baseUrl = new UriBuilder(request.Scheme, request.Host.Host, request.Host.Port ?? -1).Uri;

        httpClient.BaseAddress = baseUrl;
        HttpResponseMessage result = httpClient.GetAsync($"/api/projects/{id}").Result;

        string content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
            {
                Modifiers =
                    {
                        static typeInfo =>
                        {
                            if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
                            return;

                            foreach (JsonPropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeInfo.Properties)
                            {
                                // Strip IsRequired constraint from every property.
                                propertyInfo.IsRequired = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        };

        SpRroject.Fields project = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SpRroject.Fields>(content, options)!;

        return View(project);
    }
}

// POST: ProjectsController/Delete/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Delete(string id, IFormCollection? collection)
{
    try
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
    

Now the call of the get is working fine except in the view, the form that is used to post has the wrong url
<form action="/api/Projects/bb2062cb-c33e-4c96-82ce-63eaea699000" method="post">
        <input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Title field is required." id="Title" name="Title" value="Red Sea dummy project">
        <input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ProjectNumber field is required." id="ProjectNumber" name="ProjectNumber" value="32423">
        <input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ProjectClientNumber field is required." id="ProjectClientNumber" name="ProjectClientNumber" value="354345">
        <input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ProjectContractNumber field is required." id="ProjectContractNumber" name="ProjectContractNumber" value="345345">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger"> |
        <a href="/Projects">Back to List</a>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8JfO0mu9o-JEv7MUqlO6lpkkFM1agk2yFILDnvV-Y4Kh-k4hL8VwUKTO6ZtQXD-m7qoXoa84BYX1ekyiJPCxvS6oocXxElVFknSlZZeE0HCmqXBa3FZQyosqIf25Ch2yUC0qYYUQbDTIijzaIYzFe-I"></form>

I have no idea why the action of the Controller implementation adds /api to the form in the related view.
I tried so many things in the view, but it is always overwritten by whatever the controller will send. I'm using Razor pages.

The ControllerBase is the base class for API methods (without forms / pages). Those by default live in the /api/..... areas of your app. If you really want to have MVC-style Razor pages - inherit from Controller - not from ControllerBase

I guess you didn't read my post carefully. I'm already using Controller, not ControllerBase to call the view. Though, the controller acts like api instead of mvc.

There are 2 controller of same name, one implements ControllerBase and the other implements Controller but they are in different folders.
